# Can I play digitally bought games on Xbox (series S) on a different console by signing in to my account, like the One?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, forza-horizon

I'm looking to buy the Xbox series S, which can only be downloaded. I'm concerned that I'll have to rebuy the game if I ever decide to download it to a new or different console. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Digital copies of games are bound to your account, so as long as you're logged in to the account on which you bought the game, you'll be able to play it on any compatible console.

According to [Xbox Support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/games-apps/game-setup-and-play/playing-your-games-on-other-xbox-one-consoles):

> You can also play games you purchased digitally through Microsoft Store on any Xbox console. Here’s how.
>
> > **Note** You’ll always need to be signed in and connected to Xbox Live to play digital games.
>
> 1. On any Xbox console, sign in using your Microsoft account, and then connect to Xbox Live.
> 2. Go to **My games & apps** > **Games**.
> 3. Find the game you want to play. If the game is not yet installed, highlight the game title, press the **Menu** button , and then select **Install**.
> 4. When the game is installed, select the game from your collection, and then select **Play**.
>
> If you’re having problems trying to download a digital game, see the following article:
>
> [Troubleshoot game or app installation problems on your Xbox console](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/games-apps/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-game-or-app-installation-problems-on-xbox-one)
>
> **Things to keep in mind:**
>
> - Even though you can leave a game installed on another person’s console, they will **not** be able to play it unless they also own the game. Instead, they’ll be prompted to insert the disc or purchase a digital copy.
> - Regional restrictions may apply in some cases, as not all games are available in every country. For more information, see:
>   [Xbox locales FAQ](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/getting-started-set-up/locale-faq)
> - Each Xbox console must have either a digital or physical copy of a game. For example, if you have other consoles in your home and other people want to play the same game with you using those additional consoles, each console must have its own copy of the game.